# Смена частей списка местами

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача из книги Федорова.

Не знаю 1) как начать, 2) что делать если N нечетное

Comment: 1) разделить длину пполам 2) брать длину на половину меньше, начинать на половину позже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы поменять местами половины списка, можно воспользоваться срезами. Непосредственно половину я нахожу целочисленным делением длины списка пополам.

*P. S.: Вопрос о том, что делать в случае нечётного списка, нужно задавать скорее автору*

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    t = len(li) // 2
    result = li[t:] + li[:t]
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: *опрос о том, что делать в случае нечётного списка, * оставить центральный на месте?

Comment: @splash58 Предположим, список из 7 элементов. Если оставить центральный на месте, то получится немного странно: `[5, 6, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3]`. Я же правильно Вас понял?

Comment: а как по-другому. но это мое предположение